# Timber "resize" filter won't generate new image sizes

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

This piece of code (WordPress theme) using the "resize" of Timber filter won't generate the new size image and always returns the source image link instead.

```
<img src="{{ file.thumbnail.url|resize( 255, 300 ) }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

No errors are returned, no logs when setting WP_DEBUG to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually debugging the code in *`wp-content\plugins\timber-library\lib\Image\Operation\Resize.php`*, which generates the new images in the run method, shows that function call `wp_get_image_editor` returns a `WP_Error` object.

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor($load_filename);
```

Dumping the object gives the reason why it wasn't working:

> No editor could be selected.

Which means the PHP build installed in the server has no image manipulation extensions. After installing `php72-php-gd`, the images are generated now.